# Problem using android storage access framework with sd card and with local files directory

Tags: android, storage, scoped

I am wanting to use Android Scoped Storage for accessing both the local files directory and the SD card. My problem is with using the same functions to access both, for which I need the Uri for the local files directory.

I would have thought that the first two lines of code below would give me the Uri of the local files directory, but the third line, which is how I would use the Uri, raises an exception with this detail message:

- Invalid URI: file:///data/user/0/tl.listmster2/files

  ```
        val file = DocumentFile.fromFile(context.filesDir)
        val uri = file.uri
        val dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)
  ```

I'm sure that there a workarounds, but it would be really helpful to get a valid Uri of the local files directory, if anyone has any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is with using the same functions to access both, for which I need the Uri for the local files directory

My interpretation is that by "the same functions to access both", you were planning on using `fromTreeUri()` for both documents and files. That will not work. `fromTreeUri()` **only** works with a document tree `Uri`.

My guess is that those "same functions" should be taking a `DocumentFile` as input, not a `Uri`. Code outside of those functions can know where the `DocumentFile` came from (`fromFile()`, `fromTreeUri()`, or `fromSingleUri()`). Those functions can deal with the `DocumentFile` abstraction, using methods like `isDirectory()` and `listFiles()` to traverse the contents as needed.

> but it would be really helpful to get a valid Uri of the local files directory

There is no `Uri` based off a `File` that works with `fromTreeUri()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick any directory from device or removable micro sd card.

Or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for files.

That is how you use SAF.

Comment: Thing is, I want to use SAF to automatically load and save a few files associated with the app without user interaction. I'm trying to use the same SAF functions for the context.filesDir and for a directory on the SD card. I'm also fighting with SAF about who gets control of file extensions for my proprietary data format. I'm trying to convert my app from the standard (and far superior) file system to SAF.

Comment: SAF has no access to getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and such. And SAF is never without user interaction. For getFilesDir() and such use the usual File classes.

Comment: SAF does have access to the getFilesDir with
val dir = DocumentFile.fromFile(context.filesDir)
Unfortunately, I found it impossible to use this because of a fight with SAF over the file extension when creating a file in that directory and later finding the created file.

Comment: SAF does have access to the getFilesDir. Beyond reasonable doubt, since I have done it.

Comment: Sorry. Indeed. I tried and it does work with fromFile(). But what would be the benefit over using classic File means? And does using DocumentFile imply using SAF?

Comment: Well, I was converting a program from classic to SAF, and I wanted to continue using the Files directory for "working" type stuff. Since I converted all my storage routines to use SAF, I would have needed SAF for the Files directory. It would have worked except for a file extension problem in the Files diectory. Doesn't really matter.

Comment: It makes no sense trying to use SAF -but i think you mean using DocumentFile- for files in directories like getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDIr(). Further your app can create as many files and directories as it wants in nearly all public directories on external storage using classic File routines. Use only SAF to handle files which do not belong to your app or if you wanna write to removable micro sd card.